# How do I collect the stdout and std error from the .xcresult bundle generated by my XCUI Unit Tests?

Tags: xcode11, xcuitest

In Xcode 10 and below, the `stdout` and `stderror` of the test suite run could be found and extracted from inside the specified -resultBundlePath using this shell command:

`cp -fv $(find $resultBundlePath/1_Test -print | grep TestSuite1 | grep 'StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt' | xargs) TestSuite1Xctestrun.log"`

With Xcode 11+, this file no longer is found in the bundle.

Where and how do I extract it from the xcbundle?

Answer (score 3):

`xcrun xcresulttool --formatDescription` shows that there is a logRef key with a unique value pointing to the log that we can query for if we know the item's ID.

Using jq, I was able accomplish this task.

First we get the id of the `logRef`, then we extract its value from the `.xcresult` bundle into a text file.

```
# find the id that points to the location of the encoded file in the .xcresult bundle
id=$(xcrun xcresulttool get --format json --path Tests.xcresult | jq '.actions._values[]' | jq -r '.actionResult.logRef.id._value')
# export the log found at the the id in the .xcresult bundle
xcrun xcresulttool export --path Tests.xcresult --id $id --output-path TestsStdErrorStdout.log --type file
```

Comment: One thing to note is that this isn't the raw log.  It's actually an export from xcresulttool of an ActionLogSection object which contains the logs.  So if you export the logs from Xcode & attempt a diff, you'll notice there's additional data in the file you wouldn't expect.  My workplace added this into our parsing tool for Xcode 11 xcresult (https://github.com/ChargePoint/xcparse) if anyone would prefer a Homebrew command-line tool to do this.